# qgraph legend two rows instead of a long one

Tags: r, qgraphicsview

I am plotting my network graph with over 117 nodes. I have made it to where you can visualize a legend for the nodes, but I have to make the text really small. Is there a way I can adjust the legend to have two columns of my nodes? I have attached my code and a picture of the graph in this question.

**Network image I have**

[image: Network Image I have]

**Network image I want**
[image: Network Image I want]

Thanks!!

```
g = LoGo(dataset, normal= FALSE)
qgraph(g, layout = "spring", diag = FALSE, labels = TRUE, 
   nodeNames = rownames(g), 
   legend.cex = 0.16,vsize = 2, GLratio = 9, vsize=4, legend=TRUE, legend.cex=.6)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please also include the packages you use. Have a closer look at the link from @MrFlick

Comment: What do you mean by "adjust the legend to have two columns of my nodes"? Can you give an example of the output that you are looking for?

Comment: @Gorka I have updated my question to have a picture of what the goal of my graph should look like.

Comment: as you can see, if I am able to make the legend information two columns, instead of one, it is easier to see. I can also make the actual node font larger once I do this.